# Who are the characters in the Audience?

Tags: fate-series, fate-grand-order, fate-school-life

In *Fate/Grand Order: Himuro no Tenchi - 7-nin no Saikyou Ijin-hen* we see a bunch of Servants sitting in the Audience when Kane Himuro is on stage

[image: Front of the audience]
[image: Back of the audience]

I recognize in the first image Sakura (from *Fate/Extra* i assume), Sakata Kintoki next to her and  Hans Christian Andersen in front of her and Medusa on the far right while in the second image in the back i see the back of Mysterious Heroine X Alter and one of Medusa's sisters next to her, i think.

So i am wondering who are all the Characters in the audience and are they all Grand Order Servants? because assuming i'm right in IDing Sakura from *Fate/Extra* (the NPC Nurse) i don't recall her being a Servant (Sakura Matou i know is a Psudo Servant and the *Fate/Extra CCC* Alter Egos like Passionlip, Meltlilith and BB are in Grand Order too)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, these are from what I can tell, all servants from Grand/Order.

The Sakura you're talking about in the first image is actually BB, she's just wearing her nurse dress after her [Noble Phantasm animation.](https://youtu.be/V4Etmvrg2pk?t=154)

In order from left to right, top to bottom, these would be:

- BB
- Sakata Kintoki
- Medusa
- Osakabe-hime
- Henry Jekyll
- This one's hard to tell. Could be Okita Alter.
- Hans
- James Moriarty
- El-Melloi II / Zhuge Liang

In the back it gets a bit harder, but again from left to right:

- Paul Bunyan
- Yan Qing
- MHX Alter
- Stheno / Euryale
- Shuten-Douji
- Maybe some incarnation of Gilgamesh

I won't try with the row in front with that image since it's probably tougher... but as a bonus, the one with the spiky crown in front of Shuten is probably Ishtar.

Comment: Hard to tell one is a certain "Amazoness CEO" berserker. Some incarnation of Gilgamesh is more likely Robin Hood. Gilgamesh would never sit that far back with mere mongrels.

Comment: Also in the second to last row, Nezha,  maybe Seig, Edison, likely Ibaraki-douji's horns, someone's head or hat (Nursery Rhyme?), Ishtar, maybe Cuzilla, maybe Karna?

Comment: I thought about that Berserker as well, but makes me wonder why the glasses for everyone. Granted, I haven't seen the episode, but your suggestion makes a lot of sense anyways. I would think Green would have at least Cock Robin around or something else, which is why my guess was Gil. Gil-ko is a good kid too, and wears grey. Good suggestions for the other row, too.

Comment: Glasses is a bit of a visual gag with Kane. It makes more sense if you watch the scene (it is subbed).

Comment: This is a gag short for new years. All the detail budget probably went into the ufotable battle scene. Kogil doesn't wrap himself like that and have spiky hair, he's smooth on the top.